# Qt Design: two QDockWidgets at prescribed layout

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have a program, preliminary look of which is in the first photo. Here, the project tree takes all space below it, and the 3D-viewport and the text edit widget are stacked vertically:

[image]

However, when I try to turn that text edit into a dock widget, it places itself under the project tree as well:

[image]

I would like the layout to be as in the first photo, and the text edit to be a dock widget at the same time, but I couldn't figure, how to do this, at least in the Qt Designer. Is it possible?

Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`QMainWindow::setCorner`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner) is what you're looking for...

```
QMainWindow main_window(...);
main_window.setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
```

The above code should cause the bottom left corner of the `QMainWindow` to be occupied by the left dock area rather than the bottom dock area.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Haven't found out how to do this in the Designer though, but it's fine when compiled.